# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1476, SQLSTATE=40506, SQLERRMC=-293

Tags: db2

Why did I get below error? This error doesn't always happen. It occurred only once. This error came from ResultSet.next(). I am doing some research about it but I couldn't find the main reason. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01476n.html) is the link that I found for same SLQCODE and SQLSTATE.

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1476, SQLSTATE=40506, SQLERRMC=-293, DRIVER=3.63.123

at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:666)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vn.b(vn.java:4031)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.h(db.java:286)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:244)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.c(db.java:31)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.r.a(r.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.j.Zb(j.ja
```

DB2 version: DB2 v10.1.0.4
OS: Linux

Answer (score 0):

The underlying error (that caused the rollback) is the -293, which corresponds to SQL0293N (error accessing container). You need to check the details at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00293n.html) of the documentation.

Don't ignore this error-message, you want to find root cause, from database diagnostics files.

It may be that the issue is only with one specific container that gets occasionally accessed. Or it may have been a temporary issue according to how the container is implemented (file-system, raw, san, device etc).

If your Db2-server has good alerting at operating-system, file-system, and Db2-level then there may have been alerts about the underlying issue.

If the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, then search in the diagnostics files for references to the -1476 and then find other preceding messages. That usually gives more details.  You can use the timestamp of the error message to narrow down the diagnostics location where you may find more details. If you find that information, edit your question to include it. You might also add details of the Db2-server version and the operating system on which it runs.

Comment: No, unlikely. That would be a -964 (SQL0964N). Best practice separates the file-systems used for active transaction-logs from the file-systems used for containers.